# Pandas Series.rename not reflected in DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to rename a `column` by validating the values in the particular columns. Here is the set-up:

```
In [9]: import pandas as pd

In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:         {"unknown_field": ['bob@gmail.com', 'shirley@gmail.com', 'groza@pubg.com']}
    ...:     )

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
       unknown_field
0      bob@gmail.com
1  shirley@gmail.com
2     groza@pubg.com
```

Using a `validate_column(ser)`, which takes `Pandas.Series` object as parameter, it validates the values in that column and modifies the column name of that particular column with a pre-defined set of column names. To make it simple, in this example, the column is validated as an `email` column.

```
In [12]: def validate_column(ser):
    ...:     # Value validation method returns that this column is email column
    ...:     ser.rename('email', inplace=True)
    ...:
```

The current name of the `unknown_field` is: `unknown_field`, and as expected, the name changes to `email` after executing `validate_column` method:

```
In [13]: df.unknown_field
Out[13]: 
0        bob@gmail.com
1    shirley@gmail.com
2       groza@pubg.com
Name: unknown_field, dtype: object

In [14]: validate_column(df.unknown_field)

In [15]: df.unknown_field
Out[15]: 
0        bob@gmail.com
1    shirley@gmail.com
2       groza@pubg.com
Name: email, dtype: object
```

However, the column names within the `df` is not modified as I expected. It still named as `unknown_field` within the `df` variable:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
       unknown_field
0      bob@gmail.com
1  shirley@gmail.com
2     groza@pubg.com
```

Currently, I use the following code to manually modify the column name within my `df` variable.

```
In [17]: for col in df.select_dtypes(object):
    ...:     df.rename(columns={col: df[col].name}, inplace=True)
    ...:     

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
               email
0      bob@gmail.com
1  shirley@gmail.com
2     groza@pubg.com

In [19]:
```

### My question is:

Is there a more efficient/straightforward method for renaming the `Series` and directly reflected in the `DataFrame`?

Comment: create a dictionary with old and new column names as key value pair, pass this dict into rename .

Comment: Hi Thasin, thanks for your suggestion. I’m aware of this method but I’m afraid it wouldn’t work perfectly in my case due to the nature of the ‘randomness’ of the multiple files having different column names that I am trying to consolidate into one big file. Therefore, I decided to validate the values of each column and rename the column based on the pattern of its values. Thanks btw

Comment: Do you have duplicated column names that should be replaces with different names?

Comment: Yes, I do have some columns like `phone1` and `phone2` (max of 2 phone numbers or emails or maybe address) which I am planning to use another function to handle that column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-write your function to accept two parameters:

```
def validate_column(df, col_name):
    # Value validation method returns that this column is email column
    return df.rename({col_name : 'email'}, axis=1)
```

Now, call your function through `DataFrame.pipe`:

```
df.pipe(validate_column, col_name='unknown_field')

               email
0      bob@gmail.com
1  shirley@gmail.com
2     groza@pubg.com
```

Very clean. This is useful if you want to chain validations:

```
(df.pipe(validate_column, col_name='unknown_field')
   .pipe(validate_column, col_name='some_other_field')
   .pipe(validate_column, col_name='third_field')
)
```

... or modify `validate_column` to validate multiple columns at a time.

Note that the renaming is no longer done in-place, and whatever result is returned from `pipe` needs to be assigned back.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed, didn't know about `.pipe()` function. It makes the code looks much cleaner and thanks for the parameter addition suggestion. I was wondering if there was a `pandas` built-in method that can do this in more straightforward fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Use dataframe's rename function and set columns argument.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"unknown_field": ['bob@gmail.com', 'shirley@gmail.com', 'groza@pubg.com']})
df = df.rename(columns={'unknown_field': 'email'})
```

Output:

```
    email
0   bob@gmail.com
1   shirley@gmail.com
2   groza@pubg.com
```